Suppose that one million people will vote in a primary with Candidate A vs. Candidate B. (Details below)

Suppose that one million people will vote in a primary with Candidate A vs. Candidate B.
a. Suppose that the one million people will vote for the two candidates by flipping a coin. So, Candidate A will get one-half the votes on average. What is the standard deviation of his number of votes.
b. A small cohort of voters $n$ (much smaller than one million) becomes strongly committed to Candidate A. The remaining voters still flip a coin to vote. How big does $n$ have to be for Candidate A to win with chance $99\%$? ($P(Z > 2.3) = .01$.) What percentage of one million is $n$?

I am attaching the work I have done so far. I treated this like a binomial distribution. I'm pretty confident I got the first part down but I'm struggling with the second part. Here's my thought process:
$n$ people are committed to Candidate A. $(1,000,000 - n)$ will still flip a coin. The condition for Candidate A to win with a $99\%$ chance is what I'm not sure about. Will the condition be that the total number of votes for $A$ was > 500,000 or something else? And after determining that condition, I do not know how to proceed to find $n$.


So, since you're looking towards the condition $P(Z > 2.3)$, assuming $Z \sim N(0,1)$, you will want to figure out, for your approximating normal distribution, what $z$-score generates $2.3$.
More precisely, if $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with, what $x$ is such that
$$
P(X > x) = P(Z > 2.3)
$$
where $X$ is really meant to follow the distribution you're using for your approximation? (We call $2.3$ the $z$-score of $x$, if you've been introduced to that terminology.) Well, that $x$ is given by
$$
2.3 = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}
$$
which tells you however many standard deviations away from $\mu$ the value $x$ is.

Well, suppose $n \ll 1,000,000$ people are in that cohort. Then Candidate A is guaranteed $n$ votes, and we need to ensure $500,001-n$ from the remaining $1,000,000-n$ for a majority. Let
$$
\mu_n:= (1,000,000-n) \frac 1 2 + n
\qquad
\sigma_n^2 := \frac 1 2 \mu_n
$$
So then we're asking: if $X \sim N(\mu_n,\sigma_n^2)$, what is the minimum $n$ such that
$$
P(X>500,001-n) = P(Z > 2.3) > 0.01
$$
is true? From which I believe you can get the answer.

Part A: Your work here is correct. This is a binomial experiment, so we may treat this as a binomial distribution. Thus, our mean is
\begin{align*}
\mu
&=n\cdot p\\
&=1\,000\,000\cdot\frac{1}{2}\\
&=500\,000,
\end{align*}
and our standard deviation is
\begin{align*}
\sigma
&=\sqrt{n\cdot p \cdot q}\\
&=\sqrt{1\,000\,000\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=\sqrt{250\,000}\\
&=500.
\end{align*}
Part B: The key thing to recognize here is that we can approximate this binomial distribution by a normal distribution. There are two tests to check in general to see when one can do this (that $n\cdot p\geq5$ and $n \cdot q\geq5$). However, when the sample size is very large and when p is .5, this is a given.
We are told that n voters will vote for candidate A, leaving $1\,000\,000-n$ voters to flip a coin. Our problem is to figure out, for what n value, will the probability that candidate A wins be 99%. This is the same thing as asking, for what n value will the area under the normal distribution curve to the left of $1\,000\,000-n$ be equal to .99.
In terms of standard normal distributions (how we solve any normal distribution problem, which I assume you know), this is the same as asking for what z-score is the area under the normal distribution curve to the left of z equal to .99, or 99%. Lucky for us, they tell us this! The z-score that has .01 of the total area under the curve to the right of it, is z=2.3. Thus, this is also the z-score that has .99 of the total area under the curve to the left of it, which helps us greatly!
Now all we need to do is solve the following using the z-score formula:
$$z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$
Where $X=1\,000\,000-n$, the value we are trying to solve for. Solving for n, we see that:
$$n=498\,850$$

A is supposed to win if the number of votes is greater than 500,000. The number of random votes for A is a random variable Y  binomial with parameters $N=1000000-n$ and $p=\frac{1}{2}$
Then A wins if $n+Y>500000 \Rightarrow Y>500000-n$
We have to find the n such that $P(Y>500000-n)=1-P(Y\leq 500000-n)=0.99 \Rightarrow P(Y\leq 500000-n)=0.01$
N is large then Y can be approximated by a normal random variable with mean $Np=(1000000-n)(\frac{1}{2})$ and standard deviation $\sqrt {Npq}= \sqrt{(1000000-n)(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})}$
Then $P(Y\leq 500000-n)=N_Z(\frac{(500000-n)-Np}{\sqrt {Npq}})=0.01 \Rightarrow \frac{(500000-n)-Np}{\sqrt {Npq}}=Z_{0.01}=-2.3$
The equation to be solved is :
$\frac{(500000-n)-(1000000-n)(\frac{1}{2})}{\sqrt {(1000000-n) (\frac{1}{2})^2}}=-2.3$

why did you equate the final equation to negative 2.3? the question gives us this value (P(Z>2.3)=.01. I understand that you have changed the inequality but I'm not sure I understand why you made the value negative. I don't understand z-scores super well.
.
